# Getting org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException within my transaction

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm getting org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException while performing these steps.

```
session.beginTransaction();
TransactionEntry te = (TransactionEntry)session.get(TransactionEntry.class, primaryKey);
session.getTransaction().commit();
.
.
.
session.beginTransaction();
session.saveOrUpdate(te.getAccount());
session.delete(te);
session.delete(te.getTransaction());
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Snapshot of my model is as follows:

TransactionEntry class

```
@Entity
public class TransactionEntry {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long txnEntryId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "account")
    private Account account;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "txnId")
    private TransactionTable transaction;
}
```

Account Class

```
@Entity
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long accountId;
}
```

TransactionTable class

```
@Entity
public class TransactionTable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long txnId;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = TransactionEntry.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "transaction", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<TransactionEntry> transactionEntries;
}
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same
identifier value was already associated with the
session: [com.pratikabu.pem.model.Account#1]
```

If I remove the  `session.delete(te.getTransaction());` statement then the code is working fine or else it is throwing the above exception. Is there something I'm missing.

Comment: I will be able to check the answers tomorrow morning. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what's happening step by step:

- line `session.saveOrUpdate(te.getAccount());` attach the `Account` object (**with id 1**) to the session
- in the line `session.delete(te.getTransaction());`, before deleting, hibernate tries to load the collection of `TransactionEntry` objects (because of the cascade, the objects in the collection need to be deleted too).
- but while loading the `TransactionEntry` objects from the collection, hibernate will load the member `Account` object too because it's mapped with a [@ManyToOne](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html) annotation that has an **[EAGER](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html#fetch%28%29)** default fetch.
- when reaching the `TransactionEntry` object that corresponds to the `Account` with id 1 hibernate throws the above exception because that `Account` already exists in the session.

Comment: I like the explanation. Up votes for you.. Bt still the problem is not solved. Actually I'm fetching the `TransactionEntry` in a separate session, and I verified that there it throws `LazyInitializationException` when I access `te.getTransaction().getTransactionEntries()`. I've updated the question please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

`session.delete(te)` -- it will delete `TransactionEntry` as well as `TransactionTable` because of `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`
So `session.delete(te.getTransaction()) with this line you wont have any thing` thats why it is saying `NonUniqueObjectException`

Comment: sorry Ramesh it is the other way.. And I'm getting exception for Account class.